# Как сделать такую гистограмму?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно сверстать гистограмму как на картинке. Каждый элемент должен быть анимирован, например первый от 0 до 5%, последний от 0 до 100%. Верстка обязательно должна быть адаптивной.

Пока что думаю делать прогресс барами, но может кто то подскажет другой способ, или у кого-то может есть пример гистограммы?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не очень понятно, что значит адаптивность верстки в данном случае и какого рода анимация должна быть на элементах.

Comment: Чтобы с телефона выглядело так же как на ПК. Анимация зеленых полос должна быть от нуля до их точки остановки. Здесь 40 полос, у каждой своя точка.

Comment: Такое делают на canvas. Но лучше посмотрите на готовые решения, например, на [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) (для коммерческих проектов нужна лицензия). Эта библиотека самая мощная и гибкая из всех, что я видел, но если поискать альтернативы, то, может, найдете что-нибудь подходящее с открытой лицензией.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уже не нужно, сам сверстал

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('.p5 span').css('height','5%');
 $('.p6 span').css('height','6%');
 $('.p7 span').css('height','7%');
 $('.p8 span').css('height','8%');
 $('.p9 span').css('height','9%');
 $('.p11 span').css('height','11%');
 $('.p12 span').css('height','12%');
 $('.p13 span').css('height','13%');
 $('.p15 span').css('height','15%');
 $('.p17 span').css('height','17%');
 $('.p19 span').css('height','19%');
 $('.p21 span').css('height','21%');
 $('.p23 span').css('height','23%');
 $('.p25 span').css('height','25%');
 $('.p28 span').css('height','28%');
 $('.p32 span').css('height','32%');
 $('.p35 span').css('height','35%');
 $('.p39 span').css('height','39%');
 $('.p42 span').css('height','42%');
 $('.p47 span').css('height','47%');
 $('.p51 span').css('height','51%');
 $('.p55 span').css('height','55%');
 $('.p61 span').css('height','61%');
 $('.p65 span').css('height','65%');
 $('.p69 span').css('height','69%');
 $('.p73 span').css('height','73%');
 $('.p76 span').css('height','76%');
 $('.p79 span').css('height','79%');
 $('.p81 span').css('height','81%');
 $('.p84 span').css('height','84%');
 $('.p87 span').css('height','87%');
 $('.p89 span').css('height','89%');
 $('.p91 span').css('height','91%');
 $('.p93 span').css('height','93%');
 $('.p95 span').css('height','95%');
 $('.p96 span').css('height','96%');
 $('.p97 span').css('height','97%');
 $('.p98 span').css('height','98%');
 $('.p99 span').css('height','99%');
 $('.gr-line').css('width','602px');
 $('.violet-line').css('width','598px');
}, 500);
```

```css
ul.xAxis{margin:0;padding:0;float:left;clear:left;display:inline;}
ul.yAxis {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -66px;
}
ul.xAxis li{float:left;list-style:none;width:99.5px;}
ul.xAxis li:last-child{width:30px;margin-top:5px}
ul.yAxis li{
 list-style:none;
 height:26px;
 text-align:right;
 float:left;
 clear:left;
}
dl#csschart, dl#csschart dt, dl#csschart dd{
 margin:0;
 padding: 0 3px;
}
.progress-bar {
 background: url(http://iscr.ru/photo/1478751331_bg_chart.png) no-repeat;
    width: 651px;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 251px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.point {
    background: url(http://iscr.ru/photo/1478751584_bg_point.png) repeat-x;
    width: 602px;
    background-position: left bottom;
    margin-top: 242px;
    height: 5px;
    margin-left: -3px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}
.gr-line {
    background: url(http://iscr.ru/photo/1478751479_bg_line.png) no-repeat;
    width: 0;
 transition: width 1.5s ease-out 0.5s;
    margin-top: 188px;
    height: 5px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
}
.violet-line {
    background: url(http://iscr.ru/photo/1478751427_violet_line.png) no-repeat;
    width: 0;
    transition: width 1.5s ease-out 0.5s;
    height: 163px;
    margin-top: 56px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
}
dl#csschart dt{
 display:none;
 }
dl#csschart dd {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    width: 13px;
    padding: 0 1px;
    height: 247px;
 bottom: 0;
}
dl#csschart span{
 position:absolute;
 display:block;
 width:10px; 
 bottom:0;
 left:0; 
 z-index:1;
 color:#555;
 text-decoration:none;
 }  
dl#csschart span{
 height: 0;
 transition: height 1s ease-out 0.5s;
 background:url(http://iscr.ru/photo/1478751392_bar.png) repeat-y;
} 
dl#csschart .sub{
 margin-left:-33px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-bar">
<ul class="yAxis">
 <li> </li>
 <li> </li>
 <li> </li>
 <li> </li>
 <li> </li>
 <li> </li>
 <li> </li>
 <li>Затраты*</li>
 <li>Клиенты</li>
 <li>Прибыль</li>

</ul>
 <dl id="csschart">
  <div class="point"></div>
  <div class="gr-line"></div>
  <div class="violet-line"></div>
  <dd class="p5"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p5"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p6"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p7"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p8"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p9"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p11"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p12"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p13"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p15"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p17"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p19"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p21"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p23"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p25"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p28"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p32"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p35"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p39"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p42"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p47"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p51"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p55"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p61"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p65"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p69"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p73"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p76"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p79"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p81"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p84"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p87"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p89"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p91"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p93"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p95"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p96"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p97"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p98"><span></span></dd>
  <dd class="p99"><span></span></dd>
</dl>
<ul class="xAxis">
 <li>Старт</li>
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>3</li>
 <li>4</li>
 <li>5</li>
 <li>6</li>
</ul>
</div>
```